# Accessing the xml tag with C# and updating the content

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file that I converted from pdf to xml.

Example XML looks as follows

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <office:document xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0" xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0" xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0" xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0" xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0" xmlns:number="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:datastyle:1.0" xmlns:presentation="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:presentation:1.0" xmlns:svg="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:svg-compatible:1.0" xmlns:chart="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:chart:1.0" xmlns:dr3d="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:dr3d:1.0" xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:form="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:form:1.0" xmlns:script="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:script:1.0" xmlns:config="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:config:1.0" xmlns:ooo="http://openoffice.org/2004/office" xmlns:ooow="http://openoffice.org/2004/writer" xmlns:oooc="http://openoffice.org/2004/calc" xmlns:dom="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:smil="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:smil-compatible:1.0" xmlns:anim="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:animation:1.0" xmlns:rpt="http://openoffice.org/2005/report" xmlns:of="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:of:1.2" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:grddl="http://www.w3.org/2003/g/data-view#" xmlns:officeooo="http://openoffice.org/2009/office" xmlns:tableooo="http://openoffice.org/2009/table" xmlns:drawooo="http://openoffice.org/2010/draw" xmlns:calcext="urn:org:documentfoundation:names:experimental:calc:xmlns:calcext:1.0" xmlns:loext="urn:org:documentfoundation:names:experimental:office:xmlns:loext:1.0" xmlns:field="urn:openoffice:names:experimental:ooo-ms-interop:xmlns:field:1.0" xmlns:formx="urn:openoffice:names:experimental:ooxml-odf-interop:xmlns:form:1.0" xmlns:css3t="http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/" office:version="1.2" office:mimetype="application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics">
     <office:body>
      <office:drawing>
       <draw:page draw:name="page1" draw:style-name="dp2" draw:master-page-name="master-page3">
           <draw:frame draw:style-name="gr9" draw:text-style-name="P10" draw:layer="layout" svg:width="1.242cm" svg:height="0.357cm" svg:x="17.055cm" svg:y="11.787cm">
               <draw:text-box>
                    <text:p text:style-name="P2"><text:span text:style-name="T6">Example</text:span></text:p>
               </draw:text-box>
           </draw:frame>
       </draw:page>
      </office:drawing>
     </office:body>
    </office:document>
```

The C# code I'm trying to use:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

XmlNamespaceManager namespaces = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
namespaces.AddNamespace("xmlns:draw", "urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0");

doc.Load("invoiceto.xml");

doc.SelectSingleNode("/draw:frame/draw:text-box/text:p/text:span", namespaces).InnerText = "new value";
```

I get this error

> '' text 'namespace prefix not defined.'

I want to replace the text of example with C# but how can I get to the `<text: span text: style-name = "T6">` tag with C#?

Comment: what namespace are you using?

Comment: is all xml going to be exactly the same except the example text?

Comment: Which namespace are you talking about would you be a little more descriptive?

Comment: If an extra tag can be defined, I want to do it too or access the tag by specifying an ID

Comment: are you going to be resaving the xml?

Comment: yes i want to save and change that content "Example"

Comment: I updated the question I added namespace I didn't know this is important Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the prefix added to `XmlNamespaceManager` shouldn't include the `xmlns` part. Then you also need to add the prefix `text` besides `draw` because both will be used in the XPath expression for calling `SelectSingleNode`. Last, since the element `<draw:frame>` isn't the root element you need to either specify full path starting from the root or start the XPath using `//` (the `descendant-or-self` axis) instead:

```
XmlNamespaceManager namespaces = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
namespaces.AddNamespace("draw", "urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0");
namespaces.AddNamespace("text", "urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0");
doc.SelectSingleNode("//draw:frame/draw:text-box/text:p/text:span", namespaces).InnerText = "new value";
```

**<kbd>[dotnetfiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/46ijvy)</kbd>**

Comment: Well, if there is more than one structure from this tag, how can I parse the tags from each other by name or ID

Comment: for example [dotnetfiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/49puoc)

Comment: You can use `SelectNodes()` to get multiple elements then iterate through the result, and use [XPath predicate](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xpath/xpath_predicate.htm) to filter element by certain criteria

Comment: Anyways, if you couldn't get the desired result, please open a new question showing your attempted code

Comment: `<text:span text:style-name="T2" id="101">` `"//draw:frame/draw:text-box/text:p/text:span[@id = 101]" `So I took care of the problem, the link was a good content.